# Using lambda to test callbacks in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, redis, rspec2

I have a redis based news feed which gets items inserted into it via callbacks when certain events happen. For example, when a user makes a note on a book, it is inserted into the news feeds of the readers of the book.

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save do |note|
    notify_the note.book.readers
  end

...
end
```

Now this is fine and I'm 99% sure it works since I can look at my feed and see the notes there. My problem is with testing it on Rails 3 with the latest rspec-rails.

For some reason this passes:

```
spec/models/note_spec.rb
describe "note creation" do
  it "should notify the readers of the book the note is on" do
    @user.feed.count.should == 0
    @note.save!
    @user.feed.count.should == 1
  end
end
```

But this doesn't:

```
spec/models/note_spec.rb
describe "note creation" do
  it "should notify the readers of the book the note is on" do
    lambda do
      @note.save!
    end.should change(@user.feed, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

and I can't figure out what the difference is?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that `@note.save!` is throwing an exception, and it doesn't bubble up because it's isolated in the lambda. But if the `@note` in the second test is the *exact* same as the one in the first test, that's unlikely.

Comment: Yeah they're definitely the same.

Comment: I would tail the test log and run the two tests to see what is actually getting run. There must be something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec doesn't support the do/end syntax for this matcher. See the warning at the bottom of this page... http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Matchers/change

Comment: Sorry it's my own fault but I should have said I was using rpec2 (which afaik does support the do.. end syntax for lambda. I tried it with braces anyway and it doesn't seem to have solved the problem. I tried expect {}.to as well and that fails.

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems RSpec 2 doesn't support `do...end`. See in `lib/spec/matchers/change.rb`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use lambda and test for a change, you need to use curly brackets {} -- the do/end syntax is not supported (yet).